# Htaccess redirect from subdomain, but not it's folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have

sub.domain.com and want it to be redirected to domain.com

But there must not be redirects from e.g. sub.domain.com/folder/ or sub.domain.com/folder/index.html

Everything i've tried does not work...

For example

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/index\.html$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hm, but I have many subfolders and always add new. Cann't I exclude them all?

Comment: You can exclude all existent folders, just replace the first rewritecond with **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d**